# how to teach emacs that `'` (dead acute) + c = ç?

Tags: input-method, characters

I've set up my keyboard layout in arch with

`localectl set-x11-keymap us pc104 intl`

By default, in this layout, the `'` is a dead character. It is called a `dead acute`. In Portuguese, we are used to composing the `ç` char using `'` + `c`  = `ç` when using international US-keyboard layouts.

I don't know why, but by default GNU/Linux distros come configured so that when you type this combination `'` + `c` you get `ć`, which is an invalid char in Brazilian Portuguese.

So I did this. I've edited the following files:
`sudo vim /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`
`sudo vim /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache`

I change the line:

`"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa"`

to

"`cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"`

I also replaced "ć" with "ç" and "Ć" with "Ç" on `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.bak 

$ sed 's/ć/ç/g' < /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | sed 's/Ć/Ç/g' > Compose 
$ sudo mv Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

I also added two lines on `/etc/environment`:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla 
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

and then I restarted my computer.

And then it worked. It works fine in firefox, chromium, scite, gvim or any other gui tool. But not in Emacs. In Emacs, `' + c` insists on producing `ć`, despite my efforts.

How can I teach Emacs to produce ç and not ć when I type a dead acute `'` + `c`?

Comment: Which Emacs input method are you using?

Comment: I'm using the standard one. the one that is on by default when you don't change anything.

Comment: The note on the the `useXIM` X resource in `C-h i g (emacs)Table of Resources` might be relevant?

Comment: hum, gonna check that.

Comment: ‘useXIM’ (class ‘UseXIM’)
     Disable use of X input methods (XIM) if ‘false’ or ‘off’.  This is
     only relevant if your Emacs is built with XIM support.  It might be
     useful to turn off XIM on slow X client/server links.

Comment: But how do I set UseXIM to false or off? it's not an emacs variable.

Comment: It's an [X resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). You could set it in `~/.Xdefaults` as in this example: http://tess.oconnor.cx/config/.Xdefaults (amongst other ways of setting such resources).

Comment: I have no idea whether that's *actually* relevant to your problem, btw. Also, if Emacs wasn't "built with XIM support" then the resource would surely be ineffective, no matter what you set it to.

Comment: Yep, the usexim xresource provoked no effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put `LANG=C` before calling your emacs boostrap command.

```
LANG=C emacs
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `portuguese-prefix` input method may be what you're looking for?

e.g. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-\</kbd> `portuguese-prefix` <kbd>RET</kbd> (and then <kbd>C-\</kbd> to toggle thereafter).

<kbd>'</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> then produces `ç`

Use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-\</kbd> to see the details for an input method.

To configure this as your default input method (i.e. the one that you get by typing just <kbd>C-\</kbd>), you would add the following to your init file:

```el
(setq default-input-method "portuguese-prefix")
```

Comment: `C-h i g (emacs)Select Input Method` may also be useful to you.

Comment: Hum, ok I'll try this!

Comment: the portuguese prefix did not work. but `c-u c-x =` with point above `ç` tells me that `C-x 8 RET e7 RET` produces ç. It also tells me this:

Comment: Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
  old-name: LATIN SMALL LETTER C CEDILLA
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (99 807) ('c' '̧')

Comment: it should be `c` + `'` not `,`. strange

Comment: That's a shame. I can't help further, sorry -- this input method worked for me (in Emacs 25.2). Does `C-h C-\ ` for that input method indicate that it *should* do what you want for `' c` ? For me it says `cedilla   | ' or , | 'c -> ç   ,c -> ç` and in the lower table `'c  ç`

Comment: it tells me this:Input method: portuguese-prefix (‘PT>’ in mode line) for Latin-1
  Portuguese input method with prefix modifiers

    effect   | prefix | examples
 ------------+--------+----------
    acute    |   \='    | \='a -> á   \='\=' -> ´
    grave    |   \=`    | \=`a -> à
  circumflex |   ^    | ^a -> â
  diaeresis  |   "    | "u -> ü
    tilde    |   ~    | ~a -> ã
   cedilla   | \=' or , | \='c -> ç   ,c -> ç

Comment: Ok. so I got down to the following: if I press `'` + space + c, then a ç is produced.

Comment: which is different than pressing `'` + `c`. two keypresses versus 3. but at least I got somewhere.

Comment: Curious. Does this happen when you run `emacs -Q` as well? I'm also wondering whether your external-to-emacs input methods are in fact 'interfering' here, such that you need to type that space in order to transmit a plain `'` to emacs? Does emacs actually respond to the `'` before you type the space? For me, as soon as I type the `'` I see it in the buffer (underlined, to show that the input method is active). If you don't see the `'` until you've typed the space, I think there may be some such conflict.

Comment: I need to "escape" the `'` so that I can see it. It is called a "dead key". Us internation layouts contains such keys. the backquote is another such dead key.

Comment: A breakthrough: if I launch emacs with this line: `LANG=C emacs` then it works. see here: 
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2017-07/msg00070.html

Answer (score 0):

I got `' c` to produce `ç` with this in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<dead-acute> c") (lambda () (interactive) (insert-string "ç")))
```

Comment: `insert-string` was declared obsolete in Emacs-22 and I think it was removed in Emacs-26.  Just use `insert`.